# Is there a way to disable the new tag popups that show up if we hover over a tag?

Tags: support

Is there a way to disable the new tag popups that show up if we hover over a tag?

I have absolutely no use for them, and they are *very* distracting.

**PS:** I'd love to know why I got a captcha when asking this question initially...

Comment: The huge tooltips including part of the question, which manage to obscure random parts of the page and which force us to keep the pointer *at safe places* are not more useful...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74470/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/

Comment: You might be able to use the greasemonkey script here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24017/user-option-to-disable-sponsored-tags-in-the-tag-list

Comment: This request should be extended to include the new user-info popup jumping right into our face when hovering over the user card of those having a white triangle in the lower right of their gravatar...

Comment: @Theo: how immensely annoying :/

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to disable tag popups at this time; but you might check the scripts at

https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts

to see if anyone has submitted one to disable it. Indeed they have:

https://stackapps.com/questions/2129/hide-tag-info-popup

We think the tag wikis are important to keep up to date for the reasons explained here (tl;dr largely because users have to understand what the tags mean and what they're for to use them properly)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/

keeping them front and center with the popups is one way to accomplish that.

Comment: I agree (in principle). In practice we need to have more tag-wiki's written for it to be really useful. That'd be this community's initiative, and we are working on it.

Comment: In understand that you think they are important but could you guys try to find a less distracting way of providing that information? Most pages right now are hover minefields and nothing renders information useless more efficiently that giving it at times where it is not needed nor wanted.

Comment: Additionally, depending on hovering (with such small targets, even) is quite not accessible, and simple does not work on most touch screen devices.